# Using ASP.NET MVC, is it possible to execute a WPF .exe file after downloading it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application with a button to download an `.exe` file for an existing WPF application. It downloads fine, but when clicked in the browser window, it doesn't execute. How would I fix this?

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult downloadFile() 
{
    var fileName = string.Format("MyApp.exe", DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "_1");
    var tempOutPutPath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/File/")) + fileName;

    byte[] finalResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempOutPutPath);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempOutPutPath))
        System.IO.File.Delete(tempOutPutPath);

    if (finalResult == null || !finalResult.Any())
        throw new Exception(String.Format("No Files found"));

    return File(finalResult, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to your wpf project? Can you check if there's a BIN/DEBUG directory-- and check if there are DLL files there. Let me know what you see.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security issue, so i would say no. Imagine the disaster if links on malicous sites could download and run programs on the end users pc.

Don't know why you need it, but if you need to launch your wpf app from a browser. Then you could make a link to reference a uri scheme that points to your already installed application. You would have to add it to registry during an install routine or a one time job in your app.
[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694642/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-in-windows-10)

Hope this helps
I think this is the closest you can get to run your application from a browser. But making it launch automatically after download is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

like matcsr pointed out what you cannot force a user to execute a file in their download folder. But if what you want is to distribute your WPF app from the web then you need to setup a ClickOnce Web deployment. More info Here: [Choose a ClickOnce deployment strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-deployment-strategy?view=vs-2019)