# Is there a way to launch external .exe files and UWP apps from within my UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Basically I'd like to give users the ability to add shortcuts to other apps installed on their PC to my app so that they can launch them from within my app. I'd like for them to be able to launch Win32 apps AND UWP apps (Windows 10 Store apps). My app is not a file explorer, but users will simply have the ability to launch their favorite apps from within my app. I have my reasons for wanting this type of feature implemented. -__-

Comment: A way you could do this registering an Application to a URI Scheme to the other app.
See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694642/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-in-windows-10 
And call the uri using the launcher : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher?view=winrt-19041
This is not how windows standards are bequase you should only add uri's for your own app, but i think it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The goal is to execute EXTERNAL apps and not apps located within my app's package. Also, the links to these apps will be set at runtime and so no links are to be hard-coded. You are basically giving the user the option to click a button and browse the file system to the location of some arbitrary executable. From then on the user is able to launch the app at will from within my app, even after my app is restarted.

Comment: Use the process class to launch applications which is the same as launching from a File Explorer.  You may need to launch the shortcuts which contain startup information.

Comment: There is a UWP Process class? Can you be more specific? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way UWP apps from within my UWP app?

UWP has provide a way to query installed UWP app for current user. you could use `FindPackagesForUser` to get them. And then call `GetAppListEntriesAsync` to get app entry for each app. If you want launch the app, just call  `LaunchAsync` method. For more please refer the following sample code.

```
private async void FindBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PackageManager manager = new PackageManager();
    var packages = manager.FindPackagesForUser(string.Empty);
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {

        var appEntries = await package.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
        var firstApp = appEntries.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstApp != null)
        {
            await firstApp?.LaunchAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

**Please note**
``
Before  call `FindPackagesForUser`, you need enable  `packageQuery` capability

```
<Package
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap" >

......

 <rescap:Capability Name="packageQuery" />
```

> Is there a way to launch external .exe files

Currently, UWP has not provide such api to launch win32 app with path directly like classical desktop app, if you do want this feature, we suggest you make desktop extension for your UWP app, and get installed app and launch it within extension part.

Comment: Thanks! Finally a CLEAR response that is getting me somewhere.