# How can I prompt website user to open already installed custom thin client exe?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to prompt website user to open already installed thin client when they click on a button with their consent through browser prompt.

Following is an example, wherein, after user is authenticated github asks to launch locally installed github client.

[image: Something Like this]

Answer (score 1):

Register a URL protocol for your native app. Then in your web app, redirect to a URL that starts with that protocol.

Let's say you've set up a protocol `myuniqueappname` for the native app, prepare a URL that it can understand:

```
myuniqueappname://view/123
```

then use a link to help user navigate to it:

```html
<a href="myuniqueapp://view/123">View it on the desktop app</a>
```

The browser will prompt you to open the link in the native app:

[image: prompt]

### References

- Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
- [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694642/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-in-windows-10)
- Mac: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app
- https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x