# How to Launch a Remote Desktop Connection(Desktop application) from Blazor server side website?

Tags: blazor-server-side

Can I click a ip address, then call mstsc application automatically on a blazor server side website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to launch a remote desktop connection with blazor server.
But this will run on the server and not on the client. With the user context of the server.But if that is what you want you can do it.

Here is an example how to start mstsc:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics

<button @onclick="@ClickAction">mstsc</button>

@code {

    private void ClickAction()
    {
        string ipAddressOrName = "100.110.100.110";
        string arguments = $"/v:{ipAddressOrName}";
        Process.Start("mstsc.exe", arguments);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Jeb, thanks for your answer, what do you mean by run on the server and not on the client? do you mean the mstsc will run on host server ? not on user browser side ?

Comment: yes thats correct.

Comment: if you want to start a process from the client browser that is a different story. By default the browsers are in a sandbox and not allowed to do so. I think it is still possible. But that would be far more difficult to implement. And you would have to handle what would happen if the user is on Android or IOS etc. I never did that so i can only send you a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694642/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-in-windows-10